Why doesn't .filter() narrow items correctly when checking on an union typed property?
With TypeScript 5.5 .filter() has become better at narrowing the output type, however it doesn't seem to narrow correctly when checking on a union typed property of an object.
Consider the following two examples (TS Playground):
const example1 = [{ foo: 123 }, { foo: null }]
    .filter(item => {
        //   ^? (parameter) item: { foo: number; } | { foo:…
        return item.foo != null;
    });
const thisIsOK = example1;
//       ^? const thisIsOK: { foo: number; }[]

const example2 = [{ foo: 123 }, { foo: null }]
    .map(({ foo }) => ({ foo }))
    .filter(item => {
        //   ^? (parameter) item: { foo: number | null; }
        return item.foo != null;
    });
const notOK = example2;
//      ^? const notOK: { foo: number | null; }[]

Notice how in the first example each item has a different type (discriminated union?). In the second example however we created a new object in a .map() which "merged" the union to one type and "moved" it into the foo property. Now .filter() no longer works. Why not and what is the solution?

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069

You can still help it along with an explicit type predicate return type.

@zerkms I see the issue is closed but it still doesn't solve the issue? Do we still have to use type guards/type predicates? I'll have a look at the PR but it's 2 AM here now.

@jonrsharpe yeah possibly. It's a bit more complicated when the type of the object is complex though

It doesn't work because {foo: number | null} is not a discriminated union, so checking the foo property doesn't narrow the parent object; see ms/TS#42384. I'm not sure what "the" solution is; in the example you'd just manually write the type predicate; otherwise you can write a narrowParent helper as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

Nice @jcalz, but we still get { foo: number | null; } as part of the parent union, is it possible to only end up with { foo: number; }[]?

("parent union"? Do you mean "intersection"?) It's really up to you how to write a type predicate that suits your needs. You could write it this way instead. But use cases and edge cases need to be tested no matter what. So, shall I proceed with an answer or am I still missing something?

I found a simple solution by simply returning different types in the .map() @jcalz. I posted it as an answer but I thought your suggestion could also be helpful so I encourage you to post it as well if you want to

Hmm, I thought .map(({ foo }) => ({ foo })) was the premise of the question, I didn't realize that was something you'd change (since now you're checking for foo != null twice).

Yes thankfully in my case I could change the code, but for cases when you cannot then your solution would definitely fit the bill. Although it's a bit awkward with a second null check I think it's a nice and simple solution which I prefer over a type guard. Hopefully eventually TypeScript reaches a point where .filter() would just work without the extra gymnastics

The problem is that, in general, narrowing the apparent type of an object's property doesn't serve to narrow the apparent type of the object itself, unless the object is of a discriminated union type and the property is a discriminant property.  So when you check the foo property of {foo: number | null} it doesn't narrow the object, whereas if you check the foo property of {foo: number} | {foo: null} it does (because null is a unit type and therefore can serve as a discriminant).
There's a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#42384 to change this behavior. If that ever gets implemented, then (item: {foo: number | null}) => item.foo != null will automatically be inferred as returning a type predicate and your code will just work.
Until and unless that happens, you need to work around it.

The general workaround is to build a custom type guard function that narrows parent objects by properties, such as:
function narrowParent<T extends object, K extends keyof T, U extends T[K]>(
    o: T, k: K, guard: (x: T[K]) => x is U
): o is Extract<{ [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? U : T[P] }, T> {
    return guard(o[k])
}

which takes an object o of type T, one of its known keys k of type K, and a guard callback that can narrow from the type of o[k] to some narrower type U, and which narrows o itself to a type that looks like T except for the K property is narrowed. For example:
const x = {
    bar: "abc",
    baz: Math.random() < 0.5 ? 123 : undefined,
    qux: new Date()
}
// const x: { bar: string; baz: number | undefined; qux: Date; } 
if (narrowParent(x, "baz", x => x !== undefined)) {
    // const x: { bar: string; baz: number; qux: Date; } 
}

Here we check x.baz and it narrows x itself.
So armed with that, you can rewrite it as
const example2 = [{ foo: 123 }, { foo: null }]
    .map(({ foo }) => ({ foo }))
    .filter(item => narrowParent(item, "foo", x => x != null));
const nowOK = example2;
//      ^? const nowOK: { foo: number; }[]


Of course for any particular example you might not want the full general solution. You might decide that to just skip the whole "map-then-filter" approach in favor of a flatMap() approach:
const example3 = [{ foo: 123 }, { foo: null }]
    .flatMap(({ foo }) => (foo != null ? [{ foo }] : []));
// const example3: { foo: number; }[]

Playground link to code

This can be solved by returning a union type from the .map() instead of a single type where the property to filter on is a union type. Thanks to @jcalz for helping me finding this solution.
Solution (TS Playground):
Notice how we return different types from .map() based on the data we want to filter on.
const example3 = [{ foo: 123 }, { foo: null }]
    .map(({ foo }) => foo != null ? { foo } : undefined)
    .filter(item => {
        //   ^? (parameter) item: { foo: number; } | undefi…
        return item != null;
    });
const thisWorks = example3;
//        ^? const thisWorks: { foo: number; }[]

